# How do I call a web service from IBM Bluemix and capture the data

Tags: web-services, cloud, ibm-cloud

I have an account with IBM Bluemix. An external data provider is going to give me the access to one of their web services, which when called will get me data asynchronously. How do I call the web service and capture the data?

Comment: What code have you tried so far to access the data?  What is failing?

Comment: I have looked at the services available on Bluemix, but not sure if any of them gives me interface to call the web service. If I had to run it on my computer then I would have used either SQL Server or python.

Comment: I might go back to Bluemix support asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

You said that the web service is asynchronous, but in the context of a web application, it's more likely that the service is synchronous, but that it is being accessed asynchronously. Most likely, the service is being called for example via AJAX. The call is made to the service, and the execution then continues. When the response comes in, either the success or the failure functions (callbacks) are executed, asynchronously.
If [the service itself](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e15184/asynch.htm#WSCPT137) is asynchronous then you have to develop a more complex client based on some queue logic (or message-driven bean  or other).
Both the above described cases need you to develop an application that calls the web service and works on its response.

You can do it using [Runtimes](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cfapps/runtimes.html) or [Boilerplates](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cfapps/boilerplates.html).

There is also the [API Connect](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/apiconnect/index.html) service, that allows (among the other features) to [import](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/task_APIonPrem_createapi.html) an API definition and to [test](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/task_toolkit_testing.html) it from the API Designer test tool. However if you need to consume the data and perform some logic on it you'll need an application as described above.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the url's with any language using an AJAX call as mentioned above.  If the return type is JSON, then any language should also be able to ingest the results from the AJAX call.

Here's a node.js method I use to get data from my Bluemix applications:

```js
/*

 *  url: http or https web address that accepts POST..or GET 
 
 *  callbackFunc:  pass the name of a callback function that is in the same scope of makeAjaxCall().  you can pass NULL
 
 *  obj: the POST parameters.  I use a JSON object
 
 *  callbackParams: any parameters you want to pass to your callback function.  can be NULL.
 
 */
function makeAjaxCall(url, callbackFunc, obj, callbackParams) {
    var _data = (!isNull(obj)) ? obj : null;


    if (!isNull(_data)) {

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            //dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: _data,
            success: function (res) {
                callbackFunc(jsonStr);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                if (err.status == 500) {
                    showNotification(err.responseText);
                }
                showBusy(false);
            }
        });
    }
}



function isNull(inVar) {
    if (typeof (inVar) == 'undefined') {
        return true;
    }
    else if (typeof (inVar) == 'string') {
        if (inVar == '') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (typeof (invar) == 'int') {
        if (inVar < 1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (inVar == null) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```